# Vast: The Crystal Caverns Strategies

Tags: vast-the-crystal-caverns

My friends and I have recently gotten very interested in this game, and have been playing it more and more frequently. However, the group has noticed that some roles seem to have it much easier than others.

For example:

When we were just starting out, it seemed as though the thief had a very easy role, then as we played more we found out ways to counter it. We also felt like the cave had an easy role until we realized that everyone playing the dragon was revealing too many spaces.

My question to you is this, what strategies do you have for each role (early, mid, and late game)? How do you play that role aggressively and defensively? What are some key movements you can't ignore or forget in the early phases?